# Driving without the second lambda sensor

Tags: nissan, suzuki, o2-sensor, catalytic-converter, lambda

I recently had a problem with the catalytic converter in my Nissan Pixo (UK Registration) and Mechanic told me to replace it. I usually buy original spare parts for my car from India as my car was made in India. I bought a new catalytic converter from India for my car and the Mechanic fixed it properly here in the UK. But when finishing the job, he noticed that there was no hole for the secondary Lambda sensor in the Cat converter. There was only one hole which was on the top! Check the below pictures. Nissan Pixo is the European version of the Suzuki A-star which was sold in India. So, I usually buy spares from Suzuki which will perfectly suit my Nissan Pixo. This Cat converter got fixed perfectly but there is no space for the second Lambda sensor. MOT is coming up in 2 weeks. I am really worried now. What should I do? Does my car fail the MOT test because it doesnt have a second Lambda sensor? Or will it fail for emissions? (I am not sure whether the second sensor do anything to the engine as it only monitors the condition of the cat converter - I might be wrong). Can I drill a hole in the cat converter to fix the lambda sensor? Or what might be other solutions?

Please help!

[image: The one I should've Bought]
[image: The one I actually Bought]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drilling a hole and welding a new bung into place for the O2 sensor seems like your best course of action. Yes it can be done and that's what I'd do to fix the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But will it fail the MOT if I take it directly without doing anything?

Comment: @ManoHaran - I assume it will fail MOT because the check engine light (CEL) will be on. The 2nd O2 sensor monitors the health of the catalytic converter. Whether you don't plug one in or if you were to leave it hanging in open air, it will pop the CEL. I don't know about MOT, but here in the States it is an automatic fail. This would also be seen in a visual inspection which I assume they do for an MOT, too.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to get it welded then.

Comment: PS - The check engine light didn't come on for some reason 'yet'. I have done more than 100 miles so far.

Comment: @ManoHaran - Does the light for the CEL come on when you turn the ignition on without starting the engine? If not, I'm wondering if the mechanic did something to it to keep it from coming on at all?

Comment: Yes, it does come on when I switch on the ignition and goes away as usual. The mechanic tied the second sensor somewhere backside of the engine but I think he did it to just hide it.

Comment: Ok here is what happened: The CEL came on after a few weeks just 2 days before the MOT. The car seems to run a cycle at certain intervals to check it. I erased it and it's gone. I took the car to MOT and it passed the emission test without an issue. So the second measures only the state of the cat it seems. But still, I will get a CEL again in few weeks. My question is, how big of a job it will be to put a hole and weld a space for the o2 sensor?

Comment: @ManoHaran - If a person has the tools (drill with bits and welder), this is a relatively small job which would probably take 30-45 minutes to get it done. The only parts which are needed is a weld in O2 bung.

Comment: @Paulster2 ok cool got it thanks! Do they have to take the entire cat con out to do the job?

Comment: @ManoHaran - Quite possibly, depending on how much room is available for the modifications and welding.

Comment: @Paulster2 - In the meantime, can I use any o2 sensor simulators? I just found out that its a thing before like 2005. Its quite hard to find one online though.

Comment: @ManoHaran - Yah, actually you could use one to keep the dash light from coming on.

Comment: Any help to find it online will be greatly appreciated. I know I have been asking too many questions but thanks for answering all of it. I up voted all your reply and accepted your answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151113/discussion-between-mano-haran-and-ps2).